# Prove that among any given $n + 1$ positive integers, there are always two whose difference is divisible by $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

> Prove that among any given $n + 1$ positive integers, there are always two whose
> difference is divisible by $n$.

My Answer:

Using Pigeonhole principle:

From a set of at least $2$ different $n+1$ positive integers the difference between $n+1$ integers will always have a case where it is divisible by $n$. Because if there is $n+1$ integers which can be pigeons in this case then there must be at least $n$ holes where $n+1$ integers can divide by $n$. Although this does not mean all $n+1$ integers can be divisible by $n$ but there are cases where they can be.

Examples:

- $\frac{(16 - 13)}{2}$  is not divisible by $n$ for $n+1$ integers, where $n = 2$.
- $\frac{(15 - 13)}{ 2 }= 1$  is divisible by $n$, where $n = 2$.
- $\frac{(13-12) + (16-14)}{4}$ is not divisible by $n$, where $n = 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the pigeonhle principle can be used here, the proof you give is not very clear.

Try using as the holes the set of integers mod $n$.  Then for each of the $n+1$ given integers $m_k$ create a "pigeon" by mapping $m_k \mapsto (m_k \mod n)$.

Any two $m_k$ with the same values mod $n$ will have a difference divisible by $n$.

Now if no difference is divisible by $n$ you have fit $n+1$ pigeons into $n$ holes,
which is a contradiction.

Comment: So basically you used proof by contradiction using pigeonhole principle to show how it can be true because of the final case where no difference can be divisble by n means u can fit n+1 pigeons into n holes which contradicts the pigeonhole principle correct?

Comment: Yes.  Some real purist mathematicians dislike proof by contradiction, but when you use the pigeonhole principle it almost always comes down to a proof by contradiction -- "... and there were not enough holes to have done such-and-thus".

Comment: Ok thanks very much Mark that makes sense.

Comment: @MarkFischler what do 'purist' mathematicians find wrong with proof by contradiction? Is it because it's a little brute force?