# how to prove using pigeonhole principle there exist two of them, $a_i$ and $a_j$, such that $$ divides $a_i − a_j$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let $a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_{n+1}$ be $ + 1$ distinct positive integers, show that there exist two of them, $a_i$ and $a_j$, such that $$ divides $a_i − a_j$.How to solve this using pigeon hole principle?

Comment: What have you tried?  how many remainders are possible if you divide an integer by $n$?

Comment: Your subscript limits should match the count of  integers. Consider values of $a_k \bmod n$.

Comment: i thought taking modulo n but it does not ensure as there is no relation between integer like being consecutive to get n distinct remainder

Comment: if they we consecutive then we have n+1 distinct integers that should belong to n hole i.e. n remainder and the number that go to 0 remainder  hole their subtration should be divisible by n

Comment: Consecutive (or not) has nothing to do with the question.  How many remainders are possible on division by $n$?

Comment: but why please tell i am confuse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof involving the Pigeonhole principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965403/proof-involving-the-pigeonhole-principle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove the stronger: Namely this statement but for $n$ integers than $n$+$1$.

Assume all of the integers are distinct (mod $n$) so that we don't have simple trivial cases such as $a_i$=$0$(mod $n$). Then there are $n$-$1$ remainders (excluding $0$). So we have by the pigeonhole principle, there must be two integers with the same remainder, say $a_i$ and $a_j$. In other words, $a_i=a_j$(mod $n$), which would imply the given result.

Since it holds for $n$ numbers, it must hold for $n$+$1$ numbers.

Comment: There are $n$, not $n-1$, possible remainders $\pmod{n}$.

Comment: I fixed it @lulu c:

Comment: You claim that for any **n** integers, there exists two whose difference is a multiple of $n$? This is false, just look at $n=2$ with the integers $1$ and $2$.

Comment: No, I said one of the integers cannot be $0$ (mod $n$) or else we are done. Read carefully.

Comment: Literally the second sentence dude.

Comment: Literally a restriction you invented that isn't in the question dude. We are absolutely **not** done if one of the selected integers is divisible by $n$.

Comment: But then this would be a counterexample to the problem, which means my proof is trivial since the problem is trivial. So maybe, it should have said each $a_i$ is not divisible by $n$. (This is a counterexample since if $n$=$2$, this means (for instance) $2-1$=$1$(mod $n$)). So either my proof is wrong, or the problem is. In this case, the problem is.